# How to STOP SQL Services on multiple servers using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am newbie to Powershell though I am a DBA.
I searched for the information on how to STOP only SQL Services on multiple servers.
I am able to find how to stop services,
but how to stop any particular service like SQL on multiple servers.
This will be useful at the time of weekly maintenance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which services you are going to stop... all, or selected, and where are your server/service names are stored.

You may use Get-Service  command, it can connect multiple computers, and stop the service(s). If SQL Agent is running, you should stop sql service with "force" option.

Look at this article:  https://sqlpowershell.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/powershell-check-start-and-stop-sql-services-of-a-remote-servers/

If you apply below filter, it will find the sql services of all installed instances.

> {$_.Displayname -like "SQL Server (*"}

You may need also to apply a condition to exclude the stopped services (status = "Running")

Comment: $SQLServerTXT = "Path to SQLServers.TXT File"
 $Servers = Get-Content $SQLServersTXT
 
 foreach($Server in $Servers)
 {

Get-Service -ComputerName $server | ?{$_.Displayname -match “SQL SERVER”}#|%{$_.stop()}
}

Above will help to stop SQL services in the server list in the document

Comment: Avi, so, will you accept my answer, or anything else is required?

Comment: Let me test on my test server,will update the same soon.